# Reading Unicode files line by line C++

Tags: c++, unicode

What is the correct way to read Unicode files line by line in C++?

I am trying to read a file saved as Unicode (LE) by Windows Notepad.

Suppose the file contains simply the characters  A and B on separate lines.

In reading the file byte by byte, 
I see the following byte sequence (hex) :

FE FF 41 00 0D 00 0A 00 42 00 0D 00 0A 00

So 2 byte BOM,  2 byte 'A', 2byte CR , 2byte LF, 2 byte 'B', 2 byte CR, 2 byte LF .

I tried reading the text file using the following code:

```
   std::wifstream file("test.txt");
   file.seekg(2); // skip BOM
   std::wstring A_line;
   std::wstring B_line;
   getline(file,A_line);  // I get "A"
   getline(file,B_line);  // I get "\0B"
```

I get the same results using >> operator instead of getline

```
   file >> A_line;
   file >> B_line;
```

It appears that the single byte CR character is 
is being consumed only as the single byte.
or  CR NULL LF is being consumed but not the high byte NULL.
I would expect wifstream in text mode would read the 2byte CR and 2byte LF.

What am I doing wrong?
It does not seem right that one should have to read a text file 
byte by byte in binary mode just to parse the new lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::wifstream` exposes the wide character set to your program, which is typically UCS-2 on Windows and UTF-32 on Unix, but assumes that the input file is still using narrow characters. If you want it to behave using wide characters on disk, you need to use a `std::codecvt<wchar_t, wchar_t>` facet.

You should just be able to find your compiler's implementation of `std::codecvt<char, char>` which is also a non-converting code conversion facet, and change the chars to wchar_ts.